# Negative Lookbehind Workaround For Posix Regex

Tags: regex, posix, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I need to exclude a string from being matched if it's preceeded by a certain character, and my regex engine is POSIX.  I was able to get the desired result using a negative lookbehind on https://regexr.com/ but just discovered that won't work on my POSIX SnowFlake platform :-( .

I'm trying to standardize variations of company names and want to match the strings that end in 'COMPANY', 'CO', or 'CO.', but not match them if preceeded by an ' & '.  So 'COMPANY' would get matched in 'POWERWASH COMPANY', but not in 'JONES & COMPANY'.

Is there a way I can accomplish this in POSIX regex?  I was able to get this to work using a negative lookbehind as follows:

```
(?<!&)( COMPANY$| CO[.]?$)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
(^|[^&])( COMPANY| CO[.]?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d1y1d3/2).

Whatever you capture is usually of no importance in POSIX regex, but in other cases it is usually easy to work around using additional capturing groups and code logic.

*Regex details*:

- `(^|[^&])` - start of string or any char other than `&`
- `( COMPANY| CO[.]?)` - either a space and `COMPANY`, or a space, `CO`, an optional `.` and
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Does the use of `[.]` have an advantage over `\.` in POSIX regex? I'm asking because that seems to be the only difference between this and my answer. I admittedly don't have much experience with POSIX regex, so I thought maybe I missed something?

Comment: @41686d6564 No, `[.]` = `\.`. The `[^&]` in your regex does not match the start of string.

Comment: I think you missed the last paragraph :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use a capturing group (as you're already doing) and put the irrelevant parts *outside* of the group:

```
[^&]( COMPANY| CO\.?)$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CAGWeY/1)**.

I'm not that familiar with SnowFlake but according to [the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html), you can extract the value captured by group 1 using the `regexp_substr` method as follows:

```
regexp_substr(input, '[^&]( COMPANY| CO\.?)$', 1, 1, 'e', 1)
--                                                        ^
--                                              Group number
```

Note that `[^&]` will match any character other than '&'. If you'd like the match to succeed even if the target word is at the beginning of the string, you may use `(^|[^&])` in place of `[^&]`. In that case, you may extract the value from group 2 rather than group 1.